# Accumulation points of a recursive sequence $a_n=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)\sqrt[n]{1+2^n+(-3)^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Find all the accumulation points of the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined recursively:

> $$a_n=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)\sqrt[n]{1+2^n+(-3)^n}$$

My attempt:

$$\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)\in\left\{-\frac{1}{2},1\right\}$$

$$\sqrt[n]{1+2^n+(-3)^n}=\sqrt[n]{(-3)^n\left(\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n+\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^n+1\right)}=-3\sqrt[n]{\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n+\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^n+1}$$
I tried to manipulate with the above expression and apply the squeeze theorem, but I haven't managed to get anything useful for this problem, except:
$$\sqrt[n]{1+2^n+(-3)^n}<\sqrt[n]{3\cdot3^n}=3\sqrt[n]{3}$$ I also considered artithmetic inequalities and the comparison: $1+2^n\leq(1+2)^n$, unsuccessfully.
I would definitely examine the cases $n\pmod{6}$ or $n\pmod{3}$. How can I move further from this point and what can I do with the $n-\text{th}$ root? I thought I could see how one of the factors behaves since $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)$ alternates for $n\in\mathbb N$. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just keep with your good work regarding different remainders modulo $6$. How does, for example, the subsequence $a_{6n+4}, n\in\mathbb N$ behave? I would not be too surprised if they all converged (albeit to different limits) - which will then give you the set of all accumulation points.

Comment: That's not really a "recursive" sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $n$ is even, 
$$\tag1
(1+2^n+(-3)^n)^{1/n}=(1+2^n+3^n)^{1/n}\to3.
$$
when $n$ is odd, 
$$
(1+2^n+(-3)^n)^{1/n}\to-3.
$$
If you consider any subsequence $a_{n_k}$ that contains both even and odd $n_k$ for arbitrarily big $k$, the subsequence will fail to be convergent. So we only get convergent subsequences when the $n_k$ are eventually all even or odd. Thus the possible limits are 
$$
-\tfrac12\times3,-\tfrac12\times(-3),3,-3.
$$
That is, the accumulation points are 
$$
-\frac32,\frac32,3,-3. 
$$

---

To calculate the limit $(1)$, you have 
\begin{align}
(1+2^{2n}+(-3)^{2n})^{1/2n}&=(1+2^{2n}+3^{2n})^{1/2n}=3(1+3^{-2n}+(2/3)^{2n})^{1/2n}\\ \ \\
&=3\exp\left(\tfrac1{2n}\,\log(1+3^{-2n}+(2/3)^{2n})\right)\\ \ \\
&=3\exp\left(\tfrac{3^{-2n}+(2/3)^{2n}+o((2/3)^{4n})}{2n} \right)\\ \ \\
&\to3.
\end{align}

Comment: May U ask which rule you used in computing the limit $(1)$? Because we haven't used the $o$ notation yet. Is that Taylor series?

Comment: Yes, but you don't really need it. The stuff inside the logarithm goes to $1$, so the logarithm goes to zero. Divided by $n $, even more. So the exponential converges to  $\exp (0)=1$.

Comment: All you need is the continuity of $\exp $ and $\log $.